# how to use intro.js form npm package in meteor 1.4.1.1?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, intro.js

I am trying to use intro.js in my meteor Application.

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
// import introJs  from 'intro.js';
var introJs = require('intro.js');
import './main.html';

.....//some code here

Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    // increment the counter when button is clicked
    instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);
  },

'click #introjs'(e,i){
    console.log("call me");
    introJs("#introjs").start();
  }
});
```

but I give

> TypeError: introJs is not a function

How do I solve this problem?
thanks.

Comment: I also have the same question. Did you find anything ?

Comment: While searching I got this https://github.com/zhouzhuojie/meteor-introjs link see if it is beneficial and also let me know.

Comment: @Arjun Chaudhary  no i am trying to find  a way. see you this post on meteor forum [link](https://forums.meteor.com/t/not-working-bootstraptour-with-meteor-1-4/28859/6)

Answer (score 1):

Try: `introJs.introJs().start()`. That will do.
It's because of how the intro.js file code is written, check it with a `console.log()` on your `introJs` var.
More on this: [Why does require('intro.js') export an object with just introJs?](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/581)

Answer (score 0):

On your html file you have to add a intro element like data-intro onto your html elements wherever you want intro to handle.

```
<template name=hello>
    <a href='http://google.com/' class='introjsclass' data-intro='Hello step one!'></a>
</template
```

On your js file make sure to import intro.js and intro.css

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import introJs  from 'intro.js';
//var introJs = require('intro.js');
// you have to import the introjs css file
import '/node_modules/path to your introjs css file';
import './main.html';

.....//some code here

Template.hello.events({


'click .introjsclass':function(event){
event.preventDefault();
    console.log('call me');
    introJs('.introjsclass').start();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Vinay Prabhakaran for your attention but I am give this error : TypeError: introJs is not a function